# Stopping event propagation from an onclick handler

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

I am working on a legacy web app which I am progressively ajaxifying and have found the need to stop event propagation from an inline `onclick` handler.

Take this for example:

```
<a id="inner" onclick="return handleOnclick();" href="#">Some link</a>
```

Apart from the `onclick` handler, there are listeners added with `addEventListener`. I need that under certain conditions the `onclick` handler can stop the propagation of the event. I've tried `event.stopPropagation()` but it does not seem to work. Here's a jsfiddle to test:

http://jsfiddle.net/APQk6/985/

Any ideas?

Comment: You have to pass the event object to the event handler. But the real issue is that stopPropagation does not prevent event handlers on the same element.

Comment: Try event.preventDefault().

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18971284/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false-no-jquery

Comment: @FelixKling The event object exists (window.event), you can check in the jsfiddle. Re. "the real issue is that stopPropagation does not prevent event handlers on the same element", can you provide a reference?

Comment: `window.event` does not exist in Firefox. Just look at the documentation on MDN or quirksmode.org , event.stopPropagation only stops the event from bubbling up. (I'm on the phone, I cannot provide links right now).

Comment: @RobertMunn I am trying that already, see the jsfiddle.

Comment: @FelixKling you got me on the right track, if you post an answer based on your comments I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution based on [Felix Kling's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/218196/felix-kling) comments:

- Need to call `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` instead of `event.stopPropagation()`
- Need to pass the actual event object from the inline handler ([this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16404327/how-to-pass-event-as-argument-to-an-inline-event-handler-in-javascript) was also useful)

Here's a working solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/r95cC/3/

Comment: Oh, I knew that jQuery had `stopImmediatePropagation`, but didn't know it made it into the DOM spec now. Cool! Though I wonder what the browser support is.

Comment: Good question. It is part of the DOM level 3 spec draft (http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#widl-Event-stopImmediatePropagation). I have tested it on Desktop Chrome, Desltop Firefox, iPad and iPhone.

Comment: @kol your solution is useful as a fallback if stopImmediatePropagation is not supported :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a "cancelled" attribute. Not nice, but works.
http://jsfiddle.net/koldev/45zbA/

**HTML**

```
<script>
function handleOnclick(self) {
    self.setAttribute("cancelled", confirm('Stop event?') ? "1" : "0");
    return false;
}
</script>

<div>
    <a id="inner" onclick="return handleOnclick(this);" href="#">Some link</a>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
document.getElementById('inner').addEventListener('click', function(e){
    if (this.getAttribute("cancelled") == "1") {
        return;
    }
    alert("Listener called");
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, although it looks like `stopImmediatePropagation` is what I was looking for.