# How to focus Button in java-script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**Simply** I have this HTML document

```
<input type="text" id="my_txt" onkeypress="move_focus(event)"/>
<br>
<input type="button" id="my_btn" />
<script >
function move_focus(e)
{
    if (e.keyCode==13) $("#my_btn").focus();
}
</script>
```

What I want is: 
on key press event of input-text `my_txt`, if the pressed key is `ENTER` key move the focus to `my_btn` button.

I did it like above **BUT** that doesn't work and no any action is done when Enter key pressed.

I found more than one post in this network about this topic but most answers are complex and some me away of what I need.

**Help Please!.. Thanks in advance.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enter key press event in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/905222/enter-key-press-event-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important part for this is use of [bind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236747/use-of-the-javascript-bind-method). Bind creates a new function that will have `this` ([this](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascripts-this-with-clarity-and-master-it/)) set to the first parameter passed to bind().
So when we write `$('#my_txt').bind("enterKey")`, it actually maps `#my_txt` and event `enterKey` in same context that the function will execute in. So every time we press a key inside `input` element with id `#mytxt`, when we release the key it will check if the key pressed is `Enter Key` or not which is provided by the line `$('#my_txt').keyup(e)` which takes the [event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16404327/how-to-pass-event-as-argument-to-an-inline-event-handler-in-javascript) object as parameter. Here the event will be `keypress` event.

```js
move_focus = function move_focus(e) {
  $('#my_txt').bind("enterKey",function(e){  
    $("#my_btn").focus();
     //disable to prevent multiple enter
     $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled")
  });
  $('#my_txt').keyup(function(e){
     if(e.keyCode == 13)        //checks if the event object is a Enter Key or not
     {
      $(this).trigger("enterKey");   //explicitly triggers enterkey event with whom #my_txt is bound to
     }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="my_txt" onkeypress="move_focus(event)"/>
<br/>
<input type="button" id="my_btn" value="button" />
```

Comment: Thank you so much that works fine, But can you explain the code of function line by line (if and only if your time allow that) thank you again.

Comment: I'll write the comments on the code so that it will be useful for others searching later too.

Answer (score 3):

Keynumber 13 is an key which is used by default to accepts things (https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/), so basicly you have to override it with this:

```
e.preventDefault();
```

Whole Code

```
<input type="text" id="my_txt" onkeypress="move_focus(event)"/>
<br>
<input type="button" id="my_btn" />
<script >
function move_focus(e)
{
  e.preventDefault();
  if (e.keyCode==13) $("#my_btn").focus();
}
</script>
```

Comment: thank you for your effort, But that doesn't move the focus to button !..

Answer (score 0):

Try this example which uses jQuery:

```js
$( "#my_txt" ).keypress(function(event) {
 var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
    if(keycode == '13'){
     $( "#my_btn" ).focus();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<body> 
  <input type="text" id="my_txt"/><br>
  <input type="button" id="my_btn" value="Button" />
</body>
```

Answer (score -2):

Instead of using:

```
$("#my_btn").focus();
```

Please use:

```
document.getElementById("my_btn").focus();
```