# What's wrong with this link? <a href="#"onclick="getNextPage();">next></a>

Tags: javascript, html

I construct this link in my `main.js` file. Unfortunately, instead of calling the fuction `getNextPage` it causes my browser to scroll upwards.

`<a href="javascript:getNextPage();">` doesn’t work either.

Things do work corretly when typed into the HTML code of my page. I do however then lose my scope variables.

Any ideas?

Comment: in href use: `javascript:void(0)`, the href link is run first and it adds # to your url, so it scroll to top page. javascript:void(0) do nothing, so the href will not work and will run your function.

Comment: Try removing the `href` and please show some code for us to help or else we won't know the variable scopes you are talking about.

Comment: Code doesn't fit. Thanks I'll try it

Comment: Code doesn't fit where?

Answer (score 4):

The issue there is the `>` char within the body of the `<a>` tag. It's a character which shall be escaped (see more on [**HTML Encoding**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encodings_in_HTML)).

The HTML below should work for you:

```js
function getNextPage(){alert('Hi')};
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="getNextPage();">next&gt;</a>
```

Comment: No, the literal greater than is not great code, but it’s not causing the OP’s problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to stop the default behavior of the HTML anchor link (href="#").

For an onclick event defined inline, you must [explicitly pass the click event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16404327/how-to-pass-event-as-argument-to-an-inline-event-handler-in-javascript), so its default behavior (following the href anchor link) can be prevented:

```
<a href="#" onclick="getNextPage(event)">next></a>
```

Then, prevent it in the handler with "preventDefault":

```
<script>
function getNextPage(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log("Next page");
} 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best would be `<a href="" onclick="getNextPage();">` just like you did (without the # if you don't want the scrolling)
But it's supposed to work try to put an alert in your getNextPage function.

You should provide more information; the javascript code.
Do you get any error in the console?

Answer (score -1):

My suggestion is to use the following code

```
<a href=“” onclick=“getNextPage();”>next&gt;</a>
```

Please provide more code so that i can provide appropriate help to you.

Comment: This code won’t work with the “smart quotes” still in place.

Comment: Use this code the <a href=“” onclick=“getNextPage(event);”>next></a> instead