# How to get eventdata in Blazor/Razor

Tags: c#, events, asp.net-core, razor, blazor

I started with Blazor today while already having some experience in web-dev.
However it seems that isn't enough. I want to get the eventarguments of an onkeydown event, so I can check for an enter-key-press.

I already tried to use a function in my event to check the keypress in a separate function, and already tried directly inserting something into the onkeydown event but nothing worked.

The following is the event I want to get the keypress from.

```
<input onkeydown="" bind="@todo.Title" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `UIKeyboardEventArgs`, something like passing event as argument in [JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16404327/how-to-pass-event-as-argument-to-an-inline-event-handler-in-javascript).

```
<p id="p" onclick="doSomething(event);">
```

In Blazor you'll do it in the following way:

```
<input type="text" onkeypress="@(e => KeyWasPressed(e))" />

/* For .NET Core 3.0+ as per: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.web.keyboardeventargs?view=aspnetcore-3.1 */
@functions {
  private void KeyWasPressed(KeyboardEventArgs args)
  {
    if (args.Key == "r")
    {
      Console.WriteLine("R was pressed");
    }
  }
}

/* For old .NET Core versions */
@functions {
  private void KeyWasPressed(UIKeyboardEventArgs args)
  {
    if (args.Key == "r")
    {
      Console.WriteLine("R was pressed");
    }
  }
}
```

As @Bohring already mentioned in comments you'll still get the event arguments if you're writing `onkeypress="@KeyWasPressed"`

You can read more here about other event args: https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2018/10/01/blazor-event-handling.aspx

Comment: Ok this seems to work, thanks. The only problem I have now, is that I have to press Enter twice for it to execute my method. However if I unfocus and then click in the field again for pressing enter, it works the first time.

Comment: You can also just write `onkeypress="@KeyWasPressed"`. You still get the args.

Comment: Okay solved it now. I now use onkeyup. Works like a charm. Thanks again Razvan

Comment: Im using dotnet 3.1.102 and I had to use KeyboardEventArgs as event argument type instead of UIKeyboardEventArgs