# Changing Icon url with javascript based on mouseevent

Tags: javascript

I cannot figure out how to make my navigation hover effect work. If you visit this site:  https://sw6.boxolutions.de/ you will see the issue. I am trying to change my navigation icons on hover. Therefore i tried to add html properties `onmouseover()` and `onmouseout()` to my `a` tags. These functions are made to change the background url attribute of my `wrapper-naviagtion-icons`based on mouseevent. Somehow it is not working.

```html
<a class="nav-link main-navigation-link"
               href="{{ category_url(category) }}"
               itemprop="url"
               onmouseenter="hover()"
               onmouseleave="unhover()"
               {% if treeItem.children|length > 0 %}data-flyout-menu-trigger="{{ category.id }}"{% endif %}
                    {% if category_linknewtab(category) %}target="_blank"{% endif %}
               title="{{ name }}">
                <div class="main-navigation-link-text">
                    {# ThemeWare: Add navigation Icons - no hover #}
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="wrapper-navigation-container">
                            <div class="wrapper-naviagtion-icons"
                                style="background: url({{category.customFields.twt_modern_pro_custom_field_set__category_navigation_icon_desktop_url}}) no-repeat;">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        {% set navigation_split_title = name|split('&') %}
                        <div class="wrapper-naviagtion-text-links">
                            <span itemprop="name"><b>{{ navigation_split_title[0]|upper }}</b></span></br>
                            <span itemprop="name">{{ navigation_split_title[1]|upper }}</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <script>
                    function hover() {
                        document.querySelector(".wrapper-naviagtion-icons").style.backgroundImage = "url{{category.customFields.twt_modern_pro_custom_field_set__category_navigation_icon_desktop_url_hover}}";
                    }

                    function unhover() {
                        document.querySelector(".wrapper-naviagtion-icons").style.backgroundImage = "url({{category.customFields.twt_modern_pro_custom_field_set__category_navigation_icon_desktop_url}})";
                    }
                </script>

</a>
```

I also tried to a different way to display the hover state icon as a separate div and manipulate the `display` state on `:hover` by changing it to `display:none;`. I cannot solve this with pure css because i do safe the icon urls in a twig template variable.

Comment: I think u missed the quote in querySelector?
it should be `document.querySelector(".wrapper-naviagtion-icons")`

Comment: Hey thanks i updated site and code snipped that was one mistake. But now i have a static icon url and basically only the first icon changes?

Comment: You also missed the bracket in the `hover` function in your `backgroundImage` string: `"url({{...}})`

Answer (score 0):

### Pure css:

```css
.navigation {
  height: 65px;
  width: 65px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.icon {
  background: url(https://sw6.boxolutions.de/media/23/3d/22/1679924988/Gift-Boxen.svg) no-repeat;
}

.icon:hover {
  background: url(https://sw6.boxolutions.de/media/f7/13/14/1679925597/Kartonfinder-star.svg) no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation icon"></div>
```

### Using JQuery:

```css
.navigation {
  height: 65px;
  width: 65px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="navigation-1" class="navigation" style="background: url(https://sw6.boxolutions.de/media/23/3d/22/1679924988/Gift-Boxen.svg) no-repeat;">

</div>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#navigation-1").mouseenter(function() {
      $(this).css('background-image', "url(https://sw6.boxolutions.de/media/f7/13/14/1679925597/Kartonfinder-star.svg)")
    });
    $("#navigation-1").mouseleave(function() {
      $(this).css('background-image', "url(https://sw6.boxolutions.de/media/23/3d/22/1679924988/Gift-Boxen.svg)");
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but i cannot work with pure css because I use variables where the frontend user can insert a icon url and the template works with this as a twig template variable

Comment: Added a JQuery solution that you can repeat for each menu item. 
The important thing is that you need the element to modify instead of searching form the root of the document.

Comment: Hey thanks again for your quick answer. I should have said that earlier but i am using vue.js as my javascript framework so i do not really want to load another library. Do you know how to handle your answer in vue?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why only the first one is changing is because when you use `querySelector`, it basically get the first element that match the criteria. Example, if you have

```html
<p class="my-text">First</p>
<p class="my-text">Second</p>
<p class="my-text">Third</p>
<script>
  console.log(document.querySelector(".my-text").innerHTML) // "First"
</script>
```

To achieve what you wanted to do using javascript, here is a simplified example, basically is to show the concept:

```js
function hover(e) {
e.target.innerHTML = "Hover"
}

function unhover(e) {
e.target.innerHTML = e.target.dataset.text
}
```

```html
<p class="my-text" data-text="First" onmouseenter="hover(event)" onmouseleave="unhover(event)">First</p>
<p class="my-text" data-text="Second" onmouseenter="hover(event)" onmouseleave="unhover(event)">Second</p>
<p class="my-text" data-text="Third" onmouseenter="hover(event)" onmouseleave="unhover(event)">Third</p>
```

You can pass in `event` when you set the attribute `onmouseenter` and `onmouseleave`. Then inside `hover` function, you can know which element is user hovering by referring to `e.target`. [Refer to this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16404327/how-to-pass-event-as-argument-to-an-inline-event-handler-in-javascript).

Comment: Thanks again for your help but it is not quite my wished solution yet. I made the changes based on your recommendation. If you visit the link you will see the issue. I do not have a data-text attribute instead i have a unique attribute called data-flyout-menu-trigger. Furthermore i do not have separate classes for my elements. As you can see in my source code i only have one ```div``` called wrapper-navigation-icons that should change on hover of the ```a```tag